# Connect to Doordash API From Salesforce Apex - JWT Help

Tags: apex, api, jwt

I keep getting 401 status code returned, but using Postman it works fine, so I think I am missing something in the JWT Creation. There are not a lot of examples I can find, so hoping one of the experts here can point out what I've missed.
I've compared the JWT I get from Postman to the one in APEX and it is very different.

I have added the Doordash URL to CSP Trusted Sites, Remote Sites, and CORS.

Thanks in advance!

Method to request JWT:

```
public static String createJWT(){

        Map<String, String> claims = new Map<String, String>();
        claims.put('kid', '****');

        JWT jwt = new JWT('HS256');
        jwt.privateKey = '***';
        jwt.iss = '***';
        jwt.aud = 'doordash';
        jwt.claims = claims;
        String token = jwt.issue();

        return token;

    }
```

Method to make JWT:

```
public String issue() {
    
        String jwt = '';
    
        JSONGenerator header = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        header.writeStartObject();
        header.writeStringField('algorithm', this.alg);
        header.writeStringField('dd-ver', 'DD-JWT-V1');
        header.writeEndObject();
        String encodedHeader = base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(header.getAsString()));
            
        JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        body.writeStartObject();
        body.writeStringField('iss', this.iss);
        //body.writeStringField('sub', this.sub);
        body.writeStringField('aud', this.aud);
        Long rightNow = (dateTime.now().getTime()/1000)+1;
        body.writeNumberField('iat', rightNow);
        body.writeNumberField('exp', (rightNow + validFor));
        if (claims != null) {
            for (String claim : claims.keySet()) {
                body.writeStringField(claim, claims.get(claim));
            }
        }
        body.writeEndObject();
        
        jwt = encodedHeader + '.' + base64URLencode(Blob.valueOf(body.getAsString()));
        
        if ( this.alg == HS256 ) {
            Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(privateKey);
            Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',Blob.valueof(jwt),key);
            jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
        } else if ( this.alg == RS256 ) {
            Blob signature = null;
            
            if (cert != null ) {
                signature = Crypto.signWithCertificate('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), cert);
            } else {
                Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pkcs8);
                signature = Crypto.sign('rsa-sha256', Blob.valueOf(jwt), privateKey);
            }
            jwt += '.' + base64URLencode(signature);  
        } else if ( this.alg == NONE ) {
            jwt += '.';
        }
        
        return jwt;
    
    }
```

Comment: MAIN THING WAS MISSING = header.writeStringField('typ', 'JWT');

As soon as I post a question I figure it out.

Comment: You can add that as a self-answer; it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Main thing missing in the request was setting below property:

```
header.writeStringField('typ', 'JWT');
```